# Can't append name with message in twilio web chat app

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript, twilio

I am creating a chat web app in angular with twilio api. Currently my chat is showing and users can send messages but i want to show which user is currently sending message.

following is my http post request to twilio

```
 viewMessages():Observable<any>{
return 
  this.http.get("https://chat.twilio.com/v2/Services/"+
 this.serviceId+"/Channels/"+this.myChannelId+
"/Messages",this.httpOpt).pipe(map(data=>data));
}
```

following is type script function

```
  name=localStorage.getItem('name');
  allMessages=[];
 totalMessages:number;
 //View all messages
 viewMessage(){
 console.log(this.name+"viewName");
   this.chatBox.viewMessages().subscribe(res=>{
    this.allMessages=res.messages
    this.allMessages.forEach((message,index)=>{
    // this.allMessages[index] = this.name+message;
    message=message+this.name; 
    console.log(message+"any")
  });
  },
err=>{
  console.log(err);
})

}
```

but when  I am printing name in console it is showing message as object(inside for each) I want to append name with messages.

Comment: Is the `message` a string, or an object?

Comment: i want it string but console showing it a object

Comment: If you `console.log(JSON.stringify(message)`, what is printed? It will need to be on the line before `message=message+this.name;`

Comment: [object object] myname is printed

Comment: myname is printinng properly but message is showing as a object

Comment: It needs to be on the line before `message=message+this.name;`. Can you add the JSON to your question please?

Comment: showing object which have sid,from and other keys

Comment: Presumably it has a property which is the string you want?

Comment: I dont think..i want to append name with message .Is there any other way?If i remove foreach loop messages are working and showing fine